# Backbone.js View to render a list partially?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I plan to create a Backbone.js View for rendering a list of items. The list will grow. It seems to me that for performance reasons I should not empty and rebuild the DOM with the items. Does this make sense? How would you approach this?

Comment: Are you using one view for each list item? or just one view for the collection? Is your list changing or just growing? if it's just growing you can just append the items instead of re-rendering the entire list.

Answer (score 1):

My typical setup for this kind of thing is to use a define a Backbone.View for the `ul` or whatever containing element I have and bind that to a collection. Then define another Backbone.View to render a single list item. Instances of this view have a one-to-one relationship with the models in the collection.

Collections have different events that correspond nicely with the different types of DOM operations you would need to perform to reflect them. I map them like this:

- sync = [render entire list on first fetch]
- add = this.$append(...)
- remove = [find corresponding list view item].remove()

OK, so this code is just hammered down from memory and not tested, but you get the idea:

```
var collection = new Backbone.Collection({
  model: Backbone.Model,
  url: '/some/api/endpoint'
});

var Li = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  initialize: function(){
    this.render();
  },
  render: function(){
    var template = _.template($('li-template').html());
    this.el = template(model.toJSON());
  }
});

var Ul = Backbone.View.extend({
  collection:collection,
  el: 'ul',
  initialize: function(){
    this.listItems = [];
    this.collection.on('sync', this.addAll);
    this.collection.on('add', this.addOne);
    this.collection.on('remove', this.removeOne);
  },

  addAll: function(){
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    this.collection.forEach(function(model){
      var view = new Li({model: model});
      frag.appendChild(view.el);
      this.listItems.push(view);
    });
    this.el.appendChild(frag);
  },

  addOne: function(model){
    var view = new Li({model: model});
    this.el.appendChild(view.el);
    this.listItems.push(view);
  },

  removeOne: function(model){
    for (var i = 0, num = this.listItems.length, item; i < num; i++) {
      view = this.listItems[i];
      if (view.model.cid === model.cid) {
        this.el.removeChild(view.el);
        this.listItems.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
  }
});
```